# Одинаковый стиль в меню для ативного пункта и hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Интересует решение на css

Есть несколько пунктов в меню:

```
<div class='active'>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

И есть стили:

```
div:hover{font-weight:600}
.active{font-weight:600}
```

При наведении на любой пункт, нужно убрать оформление у активного, кроме ситуации, когда на него навели мышкой. Код для примера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что :hover также возникает на родительском контейнере.

```css
.menu:not(:hover)>.active,
.menu>div:hover {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class=menu>
  <div class='active'>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```